# Downloading chrome from debs

Tags: google-chrome

Tried d/l from PPa but they could not find the package. then d/l from deb package d/l and saved ok but saying caused a lot of output and suggested pipe it through more or less. Tried apt-get install then again could not locate package.   all info here:

```
2017-09-09 14:16:48 (207 KB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb.1’ saved [65532326/65532326]

margaret@margaret-VS273AA-ABU-CQ5226UK:~$ sudo dpkg –i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and uninstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
margaret@margaret-VS273AA-ABU-CQ5226UK:~$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
margaret@margaret-VS273AA-ABU-CQ5226UK:~$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

how do I pipe it or just get it to install please

Comment: Why do you have an _em-dash_ character preceding the _i_ in your dpkg command? That would be your problem if it's what you ran on the console. It must be a single standard dash `-` character, not an em-dash `–` as you have apparently typed.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and navigate to the directory where the file is located.
typically `cd /home/downloads`

then type: `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb.1`

If you wish to receive update notifications, you should add chrome's repository to your sources.

Comment: Installing the .deb adds the Google repository, no  user action required.

Answer (score 2):

Download Chrome from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).

Go to the Downloads folder:

```
cd Downloads/
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Alternatively you can also use Chromium which is almost the same as Chrome.

If you want to use Chromium just type:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the dev

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=linux&extra=devchannel

Step 2: try to install via Gdebi package installer

Step 3: If still fails, report to chrome team. Because DEV means version under development. Your report will improve the product.